# replace ${dummy} with variable value in string coming from JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a Json file

```
[
"Cooling":
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Cooling",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply ${dummy} text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took"
  }
]
```

I want to replace the ${dummy} to something else base on some conditions before rendering. Is this possible in react?

I am importing this file in my react App.js component 
and displaying it as:

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        {Json.map(item => (
          <div className="col-md-1">
            <hr />
            <p key={item.id}>
              {item.title}
            </p>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

here is it possible to replace the ${dummy} in the item.description before render?

Comment: Looks like a simple string replace to me, what have you tried?

Comment: @DanD Do you mean like `something ${expression}` ? I did try that but the JSON file just said wrong syntax. I wanted something like { replacestring } where replace string is a prop

Comment: `item.replace("${expression}", "my text")` is a starting point https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @DanD ahh so you are just treating the ${expression} as a string. Ya that ll work. Was just Assuming react will have something super different as I am new to react .. :p But sure this ll work thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use string replace

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        {Json.map(item => (
          <div className="col-md-1">
            <hr />
            <p key={item.id}>
              {item.title}
            </p>
            <p>
              {
                item.description.replace('${dummy}', `${your_variable}`)
              }
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```